# UIImageview click not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to swift. I am implementing the functionality for click event for UIIMageview. My Code is below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialize()
    let logout = UIImage(named: "logout.png")
    let location = UIImage(named:"location.png")
    let appIcon = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

    imgLogout.image = logout
    imgLocation.image = location
    appicon.image = appIcon
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imgLogout.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProductListController.profileImageHasBeenTapped(gesture:)))
    //this is where we add the target, since our method to track the taps is in this class
    //we can just type "self", and then put our method name in quotes for the action parameter


    //finally, this is where we add the gesture recognizer, so it actually functions correctly
    imgLogout.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}


func profileImageHasBeenTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("Triggered")

}
```

my click event is not triggered. Any body can help me from this. 
Any will be appreciated.

**XCode version is 8.3.3**

**Swift version is 3.1**

Comment: Is there a special reason that you're not using a button for this?

Comment: i need image there. so i used imageview. what is the contraint to use imageview?

Comment: Well, no there is no costraint... but that's why `UIButton` exists

Comment: Did you add `numberOfTapsRequired` and `numberOfTouchesRequired` properties to 1, 1 respectively?

Comment: Is imgLogout's property `User Interaction Enabled` is checked?

Comment: yes i tried with numberOFTapsRequired . even i got same result

Comment: This work perfect for me can you show us your whole viewController ?Check that in selector you use right viewController

Comment: ok i will check it again.

Comment: @Noorul, your code works perfect for me too. Check your ViewController, is it `ProductListController` or someOther......

Comment: plz check selector method is relevant to ProductListController class if not change to self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a `UIButton`, that is designed for that kind of usage ?

```
let logout = UIButton(type: .custom)
logout.setImage(UIImage(named: "logout.png"), forState: .normal)
logout.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.performLogout), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc
func performLogout() {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: i need image there. so i used imageview. what is the contraint to use imageview?

Comment: You can put an image in a button.
ImageView is design to show images with a very high level of performance. It's made for big jpeg or png. UIButton use UIImageView internally to show images !

Comment: Plus, UIButton inherit from UIControl, designed to be triggered and controller by the user. UIImageView is not. There is a reason that UIImageView have "UserInteractionEnabled" set to false, it's not made for that. There are sometime it's useful to make it to true, when you make a drawing canvas for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like yourchildview not in the front so try it:

```
yourparentview.bringSubview(toFront: imgLogout)
```

Answer (score 0):

`imageLogOut` frame may be out of super view's bounds, please check it.use

```
self.profileImageHasBeenTapped(gesture:)
```

instead of

```
 ProductListController.profileImageHasBeenTapped(gesture:)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    set user interaction enabled for the image.
    // for creating tap gesture recognizer 
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // create tap gesture recognizer
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTapped:")

        // add it to the image view;
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        // make sure imageView can be interacted with by user
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        //if tap is not working bring image to front view
          self.view.bringSubview(imageView)

    }
    func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
        if let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView {
            println("Image Tapped")
            //Here you can initiate your new ViewController

            }
        }
    }
```